# how can I substring at MVC. What's my fault here?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I use Substring in MVC?

```
@if (i.Aciklama.Length > 50)
{                                          
    @Html.Raw(i.Aciklama.Substring(0,50))...
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw(i.Aciklama)
}
```

Comment: Razor syntax lets you access all the primitive type methods and operators, so you can do it like usually done in c#

Comment: can you show me how to do it with code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please provide more detailed info about it. The method you have there is correct

Comment: I'd like to show you a part of the description of the article

Comment: What are the problems with your code? What did you expect to see, what really happened? Any errors (please detail)? Edit that into your question

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing Aciklama is of string type

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Aciklama).ToString().Substring(0,50)
```

Or using extensions

```
namespace YourApp.Extensions
{
  public static class StringExtensions 
  {
    public static string Truncate(this string input, int max)
    {
      if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.Length > max)
      {
         return input.Substring(0,max);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your view add using YourApp.Extensions;

```
@Model.Aciklama.Truncate(50)
```